# Vue.Js: Alias configurations

Tags: vue.js, alias, vscode-jsconfig

I am trying to make aliases for the `components` and `sub-directories` using `jsconfig.json` in my Vue.js project. But I am getting this error:

jsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@components/*": [
                "./src/components/*"
            ],
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

SomeFile.vue

```js
import GuestLayout from '@components/Layouts/GuestLayout';
```

Error:

```js
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error

...

To install it, you can run: npm install --save @components/Layouts/GuestLayout
```

I tried goggling for the issue but nothing seems to be working. This is the simplest one which found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U73TDohXmhQ

What am I doing wrong here..?

Comment: You've told typescript that this path should be included, but you have not defined the corresponding alias within webpack. without this, the transpiler has no way of knowing what that is.

Comment: Ok, but could you please elaborate. This is my first try on any frontend javascript framework.

Comment: https://dev.to/alansolitar/webpack-aliases-in-vue-js-41hp

Comment: I have tried this already, but no use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

✔ Problem solved:

The thing that did the trick for me, was setting up the configurations in `vue.config.js` instead of using the `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json`.

vue.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@Layouts': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/Layouts/'),
                '@Inputs': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/Input/'),
                '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SomeFile.vue

```js
import GuestLayout from '@Layouts/GuestLayout';
import FormGroup from '@Inputs/FormGroup';
...
```